# Как объединить 2 dataframe pandas/dask следующим образом

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

Есть 2 dataframe. примерно следующего вида:

| id | feature_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 124 |
| 3 | 125 |
| 4 | 126 |
| 5 | 127 |
| 6 | 128 |
| 7 | 129 |
| 8 | 130 |

| id | feature_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 124 |
| 3 | 125 |
| 4 | 126 |
| 5 | 321 |
| 6 | 322 |
| 7 | 323 |
| 8 | 324 |

Нужно объединить их по id так, чтобы при совпадении id и не совпадении feature_1 добавлялась строка с тем же id но другим значением feature_1. Вот такой результат должен получиться

| id | feature_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 124 |
| 3 | 125 |
| 4 | 126 |
| 5 | 321 |
| 5 | 127 |
| 6 | 322 |
| 6 | 128 |
| 7 | 323 |
| 7 | 323 |
| 8 | 324 |
| 8 | 324 |

Не обязательно чтобы таблица была отсортирована по id, главное, чтобы в результирующей таблице были все значения feature_1. Пробовал `pd.merge`, но получилось создать таблицу, с новым столбцом feature_1_y, где и были значения, которые мне нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates()
```

результат:

```
In [48]: res
Out[48]:
   id  feature_1
0   1        123
1   2        124
2   3        125
3   4        126
4   5        127
5   6        128
6   7        129
7   8        130
4   5        321
5   6        322
6   7        323
7   8        324
```

Comment: либо concat как вариант